# Errors when using Lazarus IDE on OS X

Tags: ide, debugging, pascal, lazarus

I'm trying to use Lazarus for OS X to complete a PASCAL programming assignment, and for some reason, I keep getting the following debugger error.

> Debugger Error Ooops, the debugger
>   entered the error state.  Save your
>   work now!
>
> Hit Stop, and hope the best, we're
>   pulling the plug.

Even though it tells me "Project successfully built :)" after compiling, it will always give me that debugger error.

When I rescan the FPC source directory, I get another error as well, even though I installed the FPC package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/freepascal/files/Mac%20OS%20X/2.2.4/.

The error I get for that is:

> Error
>
> The project uses target OS=darwin and
>   CPU=i386. The system.ppu for this
>   target was not found in the FPC binary
>   directories. Make sure fpc is
>   installed correctly for this target
>   and the fpc.cfg contains the right
>   directories.

then I'll click "ok" and get this error after:

> FPC Source Directory 
>   error Please
>   check the freepascal source directory.

I'm pretty sure all these errors are somehow related.

Any help for this Lazarus/PASCAL noob would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed in current SVN trunk. 
First of all you need fpc 2.4.0 and corresponding  fpc-src - download for Mac OS X i386 and install from

www.hu.freepascal.org/lazarus/

Inside a terminal emulator type

```
svn co http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/lazarus/trunk lazarus-svn
```

Check if fpc compiler is in your path (type in terminal fpc and you'll see)

cd to the lazarus-svn dir and run

make

In finder, you can click in Projects/lazarus-svn on lazarus.app to start lazarus.

However, there is still a bug affecting Intel based Mac OS X - http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=17909 The exception handling by debugger is still broken, so be prepared.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error about FPC source directory, install the FPC sources, for example from SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Mac%20OS%20X%20i386/Lazarus%200.9.28.2/fpcsrc-2.2.4-intel-macosx.dmg/download