# Is it normal to get a debugger error when exiting a Lazarus/Mac OS program?

Tags: macos, lazarus

I recently installed Lazarus (version 1.4.4) on a Mac Mini (OSX 10.10 Yosemite), including the GDB debugger. If I compile and run a simple application--like an empty form--everything goes well. When I quit the running application, however, I get a message saying

> GDB has encountered an internal error: Press "OK" to continue
>   debugging. This may NOT be safe. Press "Stop" to end the debug
>   session.

Pressing "Stop" results in a message titled "Debugger Error" saying

> Oops, the debugger entered the error state. Save your work now. Hit
>   Stop, and hope for the best; we're pulling the plug.

I click "Stop" on the whimsical message, and everything seems OK. Is this expected? In my Debugger Options neither "Show message on stop" nor "Reset debugger after each run" is selected. ... I did see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809661/errors-when-using-lazarus-ide-on-os-x) about a somewhat similar error, but it's several years old and no longer applies.

Comment: Does setting `DisableLoadSymbolsForLibraries` to `true` in `Tools > Options > Debugger > General` help?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Rik ... Unfortunately, changing that setting did not help.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to check out [this Lazarus forum topic](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,28250.msg176407.html) or ask your question there if it stays open too long here.

Comment: An *internal error* means that something unexpected happened that the debugger's code doesn't know how to handle. In no way is that ever *normal*. Neither of those errors are *whimsical* - they're both signs of a serious error. What part of *This may NOT be safe* and *save your work and hope for the best* make you think they're humorous?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem. The solution for me was to run Lazarus as an administrator.